# Several ON clause in JOIN doesn't work properly in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, ms-access-2010

The problem is really weird. The code below gives the error, that there is *unsupportable JOIN statement*

```
update ((s2t
left join tables on
S2T.[table] = Tables.TableName)
left join Columns on 
(S2T.[column] = Columns.ColumnName))

left  join s2t_source on
(   s2t_source.source_table = "money")  
set s2t.source_id = 1;
```

But then I changed join conditions on third `JOIN` this way and it started to work:

```
update ((s2t
left join tables on
S2T.[table] = Tables.TableName)
left join Columns on 
(S2T.[column] = Columns.ColumnName))
inner join s2t_source on
(    s2t_source.source_table = S2T.[table])

set s2t.source_id = 1;
```

What am I doing wrong? Firstly, I thought that problem related with `ON clauses`, that  use info from just previously joined table. However then I found [similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24123433/1739325),  which seems to be work. I'm confused. How is that possible, that changing ON clause makes the query to fail?

**upd1**: I don't think that the problem related to datatype.

`Text datatype`: s2t_source.source_table, s2t_source.source_field, S2T.[table], S2T.[column], Tables.TableName, Columns.ColumnName

`Integer datatype`: Tables.id, Columns.id, s2t.source_id

**upd2**: I'm using Access 2010. Among this 3 tables, there are only 1 foreign key between tables named `Tables` and `Columns`

`Tables.id = Columns.table_id`

Comment: can you post your column data types... i suspect "s2t_source.source_table = Tables.id" wont work because of string and int types..

Comment: @krish I cast them  to be same data type.

Comment: Access is picky about data types.. try casting.. or just convert the columns accordingly for better performance.

Comment: yes convert the columns.. what version of access are you using? and can you post your db diagram of those tables and relationship?

Comment: @krish Updated info, the problem not related with `Update` statement itself, because the error remains in `select` too

Comment: "unsupportable JOIN" mean there is an issue with joining your tables.. can you post what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s2t_source.source_table = "money"
```

...is not a JOIN Condition but a WHERE Condition. The right hand site variable should contain something with the previous tables/joins.

Not knowing the context, I can only guess a solution:

```
update ((s2t
left join tables on
S2T.[table] = Tables.TableName)
left join Columns on 
(S2T.[column] = Columns.ColumnName))
left join s2t_source on
(    s2t_source.source_table = S2T.[table])
set s2t.source_id = 1
WHERE s2t_source.source_table = "money";
```

Comment: The right hand site variable should contain something with the previous tables/joins.    - but why?

Comment: In a JOIN of two tables, sql compares a key from the left table with a key from the right table. 

leftTableName INNER/LEFT/RIGHT JOIN rightTableName
ON leftTableColumnName = rightTbaleColumnName

I am new at Stackoverflow so I do not know if links are allowed, but look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Without this key comparison, it would create a Join where every dataset from left table is combined with every dataset from the right table. An that would be enourmous

Comment: Another explanation: In a SELECT statement with a JOIN, you want to take two rows from different tables and show it in one row in the SELECT-result. SQL needs an indicator, which rows should be combined. This is provided by comparison of the keys in the ON statement